# Editing layer symbol from pyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, editing

I want to do ->Layers Panel -> select Layer -> go to properties -> change style -> changing angle from python .

Please suggest required python api.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You seem to have already selected your Python API (pyQGIS).  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: I solved this problem anyway.  -->>mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()-->>
n = mapcanvas.layerCount() -->>layers = [mapcanvas.layer(i) for i in range(n)] -->> symbols = layers[0].rendererV2().symbols() -->> sym = symbols[0] -->>     sym.setAngle(theta) -- >> layers[0].triggerRepaint()

Comment: I've re-opened your question so that you can add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem this way:

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
n = mapcanvas.layerCount()
layers = [mapcanvas.layer(i) for i in range(n)] 
symbols = layers[0].rendererV2().symbols() 
sym = symbols[0]
sym.setAngle(theta) # theta is rotate the symbol dynamically
layers[0].triggerRepaint()
```